# Usage of Interrogative adjective

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I have these sentences (both of them are in a book series, and are written by Indian):

> 1)Which football team wins the game?
>
> 2)What materials are used to make it?

I wonder if they are grammatically correct? I think "what" and "which" in this case are interrogative adjectives. I have got some similar sentences on various websites, but I'm still not sure:

> a)Which coat is Paul’s?
>
> b)which book belongs to you , this or that ? (This one is from a Vietnamese's website, it says that "which book" plays subject role)
> Hope to receive your help. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In your examples, "which" and "what" are called interrogative determiners. We stopped calling them adjectives some years ago.

Answer (score 1):

First hit on Google for "interrogative adjectives":

http://grammar-monster.com/glossary/interrogative_adjectives.htm

So yes, you are correct and it's easily checked.

In terms of correct grammar, though - check your use of "wins", as this seems odd unless this is a sentence fragment ("which football team wins the game if it's a nil-nil tie at the end" - and even that would be better as "would win" as it's a conditional clause).

https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/conditional-sentences/

Comment: In the book which I'm editing, they use "Which football team wins the game?" as a question. That's the problem.
But, I just found another similar sentence in http://www.k12reader.com/term/interrogative-adjectives/ :

>Which team scored the highest points in the academic bowl?

I'm still thinking about this.

Comment: Context is everything here. "Two teams meet on the field. Which team wins? It depends on ..." is fine, as an example. That was my point (perhaps not well-made): it's hard to tell if this is correct with just that sentence in isolation.